# Comparing a database field with date

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psql

I'm trying to compare a field with an actual date but I am stuck with this error "'Certificate' object is not subscriptable"

```
if datetime.datetime.strptime(c.certificate['date_certified'], '%Y-%m-%d').date() >= datetime.date('2016-01-01'):
```

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong and the possible solution for it?

Definition of Component and Certificate model

```
class Component(models.Model):
certificate = models.ForeignKey(
    Certificate,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    verbose_name=_('Certificate'),
    help_text=_('Certificates are named after its first assigned component.'))


class Certificate(models.Model):
date_certified = models.DateField(
    null=True, verbose_name=_('Date certified'))
```

Error Messages:

```
if datetime.datetime.strptime(c.certificate.date_certified, '%Y-%m-%d').date() >= datetime.date('2016-01-01'):
```

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date

```
field_date = (str(c.certificate.date_certified))
        if datetime.datetime.strptime(field_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() >= datetime.date('2016-01-01'):
```

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

I tried some ways but keep getting str, int errors

Comment: You have to provide more details, for example some parts of your `models.py`.

Comment: What is the certificate object? A dictionary, a model, or something else? Provide the definition of certificate object to answer this.

Comment: `def print_info_person_new_certified_component():
    for c in Component.objects.all():
        if c.certificate:
            if datetime.datetime.strptime(c.certificate['date_certified'], '%Y-%m-%d').date() >= datetime.date('2016-01-01'):
                    print('First name: ' + c.in_house_responsibility.first_name)`

Comment: Certificate is a model defined in different models.py file. I need to print some values if that condition gets executes

Comment: Please show the definition of the Component and Certficate models. And don't write code in comments; put it as an update to the question.

Comment: add the Component model code to the question so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't access model fields via dictionary notation; you use dot notation. You are already doing so for `c.certificate`; you need to do the same for attributes of the certificate field itself, just as you do for  `c.in_house_responsibility.first_name`.

```
if c.certificate.date_certified ...
```

Comment: Thank you. It got resolved but I'm facing another issue in the same code. If you could look into it.

Comment: @Ressaq For different problems, please open a new question.

Comment: `date_certified` is already a datetime. Why do you want to call `strptime` on it?